# Query Function Google Sheets Returns Odd Result

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I used the query function in Google Sheets to retrieve some data. Unfortunately, it returned a result like below

[image: Query Result]

on the contrary, the raw data is like this

[image: Raw Data]

Does anyone know what caused it?

Comment: It should give you error `Array was not expanded.....`. However what result are you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting it to return the number to be in each row.

Answer (score 0):

The `QUERY` is assuming that your data has 11 header rows. Set the `[headers]` parameter to 0.

```cpp
=QUERY(Database!A2:N,"select A",0)
```

However, if you want to return column A from **Database!A2:N**, you don't need `QUERY`, you can simply use [array literals](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en).

```cpp
={Database!A2:A}
```